# How to create an array of Random numbers?

Tags: java

I tried to create an array of Random Numbers between 1 to 10 but I am getting a compilation Error. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong in my code?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Random {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr[] = new int[1000];
        int num;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <=arr.length; i++){
            num = 1+ rand.nextInt(10);
            arr[i] = num;
            System.out.println("Random No. Index: "+i+"\t Value : "+arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we guess which error you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fill an array with random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380991/fill-an-array-with-random-numbers)

Comment: num = 1+ rand.nextInt(10);    /*the error exists in this line, it says nextInt() method does not exists for Random class, however the same works at other places*/

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your class other than `Random`. Your name covers (makes invisible)
the `Random` class from the `java.util` package and you do need that class in your code.

For example, this code will compile and run fine.

```
import java.util.*;

class Random123 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int arr[] = new int[1000];
        int num;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            num = 1 + rand.nextInt(10);
            arr[i] = num;
            System.out.println("Random No. Index: " + i + "\t Value : " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You created a `Random` class which uses the existing `java.util.Random` class, which causes conflicts. Rename your class.

Comment: It's kinda funny how often this exact same error appears on SO. Always with Random as a name of the test class xD

Answer (score 2):

Your class is named Random and you are importing `java.util.Random`. I suspect that's the issue. So if you change the name of your class, this should work.

Also, your loop condition is not right. Change `i <= arr.length;` to `i < arr.length` or you will have a boundary issue (you'll write to `arr[1000]`).