# arrays of random numbers

Tags: arrays, random

hello everyone I got this codes but I need to make some constraint on my arrays: `public static void main (String[] args)`

```
{Random myRand = new Random ();

// Pick array size T from 1 to 100.
int T = 1 + myRand.nextInt(5);
System.out.println("T="+(T));
int C = 1 + myRand.nextInt(100);
System.out.println("C="+(C));

// Declare array of size T.
int [] production_cost=new int [T];
int []stock1= new int [T];
int[]stock2= new int [T];
int[]fix_cost1= new int [T];
int[]fix_cost2= new int [T];
int[] Demands=new int[T];
// Fill the array with random numbers.
 {for (int i=0;  i< T; i++){
  production_cost[i] = myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(0,20));
   stock1[i] = myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(0, 20));
   stock2[i]= myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(0,20));

  fix_cost1[i]=myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(10, 20) );
  fix_cost2[i]=myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(20,30));
  Demands[i] = myRand.nextInt(Integer.max(1,C));}
    System.out.println("p2::"+Arrays.toString(production_cost));
    System.out.println("h1::"+Arrays.toString(stock1));
    System.out.println("h2::"+Arrays.toString(stock2));
    System.out.println("K1::"+Arrays.toString(fix_cost1));
    System.out.println("K2::"+Arrays.toString(fix_cost2));
    System.out.println("d::"+Arrays.toString(Demands));
```

Comment: now I need all my numbers in T periods( size of arrays ):
 p2(i)+K1(i)+K2(i)<p2(i+1)+h1(i)+h2(i)+k1(i=

Comment: now I need all my numbers in T periods( size of arrays ):
 p2(i)+K1(i)+K2(i)<p2(i+1)+K1(i+1)+K2(i+1)+h1(i)+h2(i)

Answer (score 0):

You can see this link : [Fill an array with random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380991/fill-an-array-with-random-numbers)

> You need to add logic to assign random values to double[] array using
>   randomFill method.
>
> Change
>
> public static double[] list(){
>
> ```
> anArray = new double[10]; 
>
> return anArray;  }
> ```
>
> To
>
> ```
> public static double[] list() {
>
> anArray = new double[10];
>
>     for(int i=0;i<anArray.length;i++)
>
>     {
>
>        anArray[i] = randomFill();
>
>     }
>
>    return anArray; }
> ```
>
> Then you can call methods, including list() and print() in main method to generate random double values and print the
>   double[] array in console.
>
> ```
>   public static void main(String args[]) {
>
>     list(); print();  }
> ```
>
> One result is as follows:
>
> -2.89783865E8
>
> 1.605018025E9
>
> -1.55668528E9
>
> -1.589135498E9
>
> -6.33159518E8
>
> -1.038278095E9
>
> -4.2632203E8
>
> 1.310182951E9
>
> 1.350639892E9
>
> 6.7543543E7